# Can we use SQL Server as a primary data storage for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sql-server

Is it possible to use external SQL Server as a primary data storage for SharePoint 2013?

Having this implemented we can generate reports, query data and it would become very very powerful to use.

Or

Is there a way to keep on using existing content databases and using external SQL Server as a secondary data storage at the same time. So I want it to be like redundant data in SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as the database can be accessed through the SharePoint installed server, there is no issue if the connectivity is strong. If you need to have a secondary database which store some other data which are not used by SharePoint itself, you can use Business Connectivity Services.

Having both databases in the same server is fine. But if you are planning to scale the SharePoint SQL databases across multiple database servers in future, I would suggest storing secondary data in another sever. It all depends on the database size, if it is a matter of 4-5 SQL tables with lower amounts of rows in each, its a waste having a separate SQL server for that in terms of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS packages and do a data transfer to a another SQL Server. Then you can have your reports pointing to that database server.